# Change button text after method execute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have a button that the text is "IMPORT CSV",when i click the button i change the text with like this method and open the page CSV.aspx:

```
protected void lnkImportarCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lnkImportarCSV.Text = "Carregando...";
            string pagina = "CSV.aspx";
            string script = "<script>window.open('" + pagina + "','_self');</script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "temp", script, false);
        }
```

In the page CSV.aspx i use a method to create the CSV file,but after it finishes and download,the button continues Loading,don't change back to Import CSV.I put this function in the last from the page Provision.aspx,that is the page that calls the CSV.aspx
Someone knows what i'm doing wrong?

```
                    $("#<%=lnkImportarCSV.ClientID%>").text("Import CSV");
```

---

I use this function,on click in the button it calls and download.

```
function mudarBotao() {

             $("#<%=lnkImportarCSV.ClientID%>").text("Carregando...");              
$.ajax({
url:"CSV.aspx",
success: function() {
   window.location = 'CSV.aspx';
         $("#<%=lnkImportarCSV.ClientID%>").text("Importar CSV");
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Do you ever call the `mudarBotao` function?  If so, where?

Comment: I changed,i don't use a function anymore,but i don't work,it just call the jquey when the page starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have yo control when you have loaded your CSV then use a promise yo change the text, for example

```
$.ajax({
url:"CSV.aspx",
success: function(){
    //Your code here
});
```